# Use of slice(x,y) function in python

Tags: python, numpy

What exactly does the following code do?

```
     slice(x,y)
```

x,y are integers and it is being called on an object i.e.

```
     def view(self):
        return slice(self.x,self.y)
```

I am unfamiliar with Python libraries and haven't been able to find it explained clearly anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-slice). The function returns a slice object which can be used to slice, e.g., a list. For example:

```
>>> my_slice = slice(0, 1)
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> my_list[my_slice]
[1]
```

This allows you to programmatically slice a list, instead of writing `my_list[0:1]`.